# C++0x decltype and the scope resolution operator

Tags: c++, c++11, typeof, decltype, scope-resolution

With a class such as Foo:

```
struct Foo { static const int i = 9; };
```

I find that GCC 4.5 will reject the following

```
Foo f;
int x = decltype(f)::i;
```

It will work if I use an intermediate typedef, such as:

```
typedef decltype(f) ftype;
int x = ftype::i;
```

but I prefer to keep the namespace clean. I thought precedence may be an issue, so I've also tried parentheses, but no luck. Is it impossible as presented, or is there a piece of syntax that can help me?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is valid C++0x to say `decltype(f)::i`. GCC just doesn't support it yet. You can work it around with an identity template

```
template<typename T> struct identity { typedef T type; };
int x = identity<decltype(f)>::type::i;
```

`identity` is part of the `boost::mpl` namespace.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 suffers from this problem as well. Nice workaround.