# Accessing static fields by using decltype

Tags: c++, g++, c++11, decltype

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++0x decltype and the scope resolution operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525587/c0x-decltype-and-the-scope-resolution-operator)

Compiling next example using g++ 4.6.1:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    static const int v = 1;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    std::cout << decltype(a)::v << std::endl;
}
```

will produce next compiling errors:

```
error: expected primary-expression before 'decltype'
error: expected ';' before 'decltype'
```

Is this according to the standard? Or, is it a g++'s quirk?

Comment: if you had typed `A::v` , it'd have also saved you from more typing :D

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: And if it were `std::map<this_long_type_name, that_long_template<other_type_name>> m; auto a = m.begin();`.... then would writing the typename instead of `decltype(a)` be a savings?

Comment: @BenVoigt Not really a dupe, and I don't like the answer to that question. The answer to my question is in that question

Comment: @VJovic: Apart from the fact that his class is named `Foo` instead of `A`, and the static member is `i` instead of `v`, there's no difference at all.  litb offered a second workaround, `std::identity`.  And "the answer to my question is in that question" is also grounds for closure as a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if the compiler isn't recognizing the `decltype` keyword.

G++ 4.6.1 is new enough to include the `decltype` keyword.  Did you enable C++11 mode with `-std=gnu++0x` or `-std=c++0x`?

The C++ grammar does permit a *decltype-specifier* to appear before `::` in a *qualified-id*, so the code will be accepted by a conforming compiler.  The error message is wrong, `decltype(a)::v` is a valid *qualified-id*, which is a *primary-expression*.

As a workaround, you can use a typedef.  Example: http://ideone.com/clone/7FKUJ

Comment: yes, I enabled c++0x std compilation. Oh well, I'll just use a typedef workaround for now

Comment: @BenVoigt: That the compiler is not recognizing the `decltype` keyword.

Comment: your ideone link seems to have been removed (it just links to the start page). Any chance you remember what you typed in that one?

Comment: @Default: The question this is a dupe of shows how to use `typedef` as a workaround (and yes, ideone deleting code after they've promised to keep it available "Forever." is annoying)

Answer (score 1):

It is Standard, or at least, it certainly *was*. I believe that there was a DR filed about this, and it might have been fixed in the final Standard but it might be due for a fix in the next Standard. It is as simple as that a `decltype` is not a valid grammatical production before `::`.

Comment: Yes, it made it into C++11 at the last minute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525587/c0x-decltype-and-the-scope-resolution-operator

Comment: Good catch Johannes, this is a dupe.