# STL iterator loops

Tags: c++, stl, vector, std

I wrote this code:

```
#define VECTOR_LOOP_V(X) for (vector<typeof(X)>::iterator it = X.begin(); it != X.end(); it++)
```

to make it faster to write for loops for vectors but for some reason it does not work, and when I try to compile it it gives me really, really long error message.

```
 test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:20:5: error: conversion from ‘std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::v
```

etc..

Comment: Trust me, for C++, that is a __really, really short__ error message.

Comment: You should write the complete error message, not just arbitrarily cut somewhere. I bet the first characters cut out say something like `std::vector< std::vector< std::basic_string...` which should give you a hint on what the left hand side of the copy construction is...

Comment: C++11 not available to you, I guess?  Range-based `for` loops are the new hotness.

Comment: And if you don't have range-based `for` yet, try Boost FOREACH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because `typeof(X)` yields `std::vector` type and so the macro expands to something like:

```
for (vector<std::vector<...> >::iterator it = X.begin(); it != X.end(); it++)
```

Also, your macro would fail if `X` is constant, in which case `const_iterator` should be used. There are tons of other problems, but at any rate, what you were trying to do is something like this:

```
#define VECTOR_LOOP_V(X) \
    for (typeof(X.begin()) it = X.begin(), eit = X.end(); it != eit; ++it)
```

.. and here is some usage example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#define VECTOR_LOOP_V(X) \
    for (typeof(X.begin()) it = X.begin(), eit = X.end(); it != eit; ++it)

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);
    v.push_back(4);
    v.push_back(5);
    VECTOR_LOOP_V(v) {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Note, however, that `typeof` is not a standard C++ (see [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986418/typeid-and-typeof-in-c)).

All in all, you are better off using [BOOST_FOREACH](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/foreach.html) (or at least see how it is implemented there) or C++11 [range-based for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) loop.

P.S.: Do not use the STL abbreviation unless you really mean [STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) and not [C++ Standard Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++_Standard_Library) (which you can refer to as, say, stdlib).

Comment: Thank you! I will look into range-based loops, and your info was really useful!

Answer (score 4):

```
#define VECTOR_LOOP_V(X) \
     for (vector<typeof(X)>::iterator it = X.begin(); \
          it != X.end(); it++)
```

How do you intend on using the macro? It looks like `X` is the container, in which case, the first part of the `for` should be something like `typeof(X)::iterator` (don't even know if that is legal, since `typeof` is not standard and have never used).

Alternatively, you can just use boost::foreach which provides a similar although a bit richer macro, with the advantage that it is *safer* in many respects. For example, your macro will break awfully if the argument is a function call that returns by value:

```
std::vector<int> f();
VECTOR_LOOP_V( f() ) {
   std::cout << *it << "\n";
}
```

The problem is as with almost all macros that you evaluate the arguments multiple times, and in your case `it` will be an iterator into one `std::vector<int>` and termination condition will try to compare it with an iterator from a different `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: It would be valid for `decltype` in C++11, but it's not properly supported yet: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5525623/168175

Comment: @Flexo, that answer is over a year old, G++ 4.7 handles it fine.

Comment: @JonathanWakely - really? I couldn't make it work when I tried on 4.7 the other day, in a (similar) scenario.

Comment: Maybe you just forgot `-std=c++11`?